# Rotation of a detected rectangle in an image

Tags: python, opencv, contour, affinetransform, object-recognition

I need to extract a detected rectangle from an image. Rectangles are rotated in arbitrary degrees which are unknown. I have seen this post: [How to straighten a rotated rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9lXj.jpg)

But there are two problems:

1. How to calculate 'theta', which is solvable mathematically.
2. The code snippet in this post works only for `cv` not `cv2`.

Anybody have better solutions than this post? A solution completely developed in `cv2`

I have used RotateRect function. In both cases I have detected the rectangles and draw them. The problem is the angle. In both cases angels are detected negative. at least one of them should be positive. That,s why I can not rotate them correctly according to link. Please take a look at the photos I attached to the question.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use `RotatedRect`, which has the angel information. Or you can compute the angle from the vertices coordinates. So do you need the math for 1) ? Regarding 2), just use new syntax: `CreateImage` becomes `imread`, etc... Then, **what you've tried so far?** How are your rectangles stored? Do you have the vertices coordinates? Are they ordered? What have you tried to compute the angle?

Comment: I have used RotateRect function. In both cases I have detected the rectangles and draw them. The problem is the angle. In both cases angels are detected negative. at least one of them should be positive. That,s why I can not rotate them correctly according to link. Please take a look at the photos I attached to the question.

Comment: angle of RotatedRect may seem counter-intuitive sometime, but it's correct! Try this: if width > height, add PI/2 to the angle, and swap width and height.

Comment: Perfect Miki. As usual. !!!!